# Odoo Computed fields cant work in function

Tags: python, odoo-10, computed-field

in another project, I used compute field like this on a function and it works. But why this one is not working?
Here is my code :

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):

_inherit = 'hr.payslip'

gaji_pokok = fields.Integer(string="Gaji Pokok")
t_lembur = fields.Integer(string="Tunjangan Lembur")
t_transportasi = fields.Integer(string="Tunjangan Transportasi")
bonus = fields.Integer(string="Bonus")
jumlah_kerja = fields.Integer(string="Jumlah Jam Kerja")
libur = fields.Integer(string="Cuti")
total_pendapatan = fields.Monetary(compute = '_compute_gaji', readonly=True, string="Total Gaji")

@api.one
@api.depends('gaji_pokok', 't_lembur', 't_transportasi', 'bonus', 'jumlah_kerja', 'libur')
def _compute_gaji(self):
    for sal in self:
        if sal.gaji_pokok is not False:
        sal.total_pendapatan = sal.gaji_pokok + sal.t_lembur + sal.t_transportasi + sal.bonus + sal.jumlah_kerja + sal.libur
```

Here is my xml (not all the code I show)

```
        <xpath expr="//page[1]" position="after">
            <form colspan="4" nolabel="1">
                    <page string="Pendapatan Karyawan">
                        <separator string="Pendapatan Karyawan"/>
                            <group col="4">
                                    <field name="jumlah_kerja"/>
                                    <field name="libur"/>
                                    <field name="gaji_pokok"/>
                                    <field name="t_lembur"/>
                                    <field name="t_transportasi"/>
                                    <field name="bonus"/>
                                    <field name="total_pendapatan"/>
                            </group>
                    </page>
            </form>
        </xpath>
```

My error message is "field total_pendapatan doesnt exist"

Anyone can help me about this?

Comment: it depends of which odoo version this code was written  and in which version you are deploying it.

Comment: I used odoo v10. DO you have solution about this?

Comment: in odoo10, there is no `import from openerp`

Comment: replace `openerp` with `odoo` in import line

Comment: post your error msg

Comment: In my another project, used import from openerp but it works. When I add total_pendapatan with monetary field than there is compute field in there, it desnot works. Do you help me?

Comment: my error message is "field total_pendapatan doesnot exist"

Comment: have you added in view file ? and update your module ?

Comment: Ya, I have added in view file and I have done update my module. But it cant works

Comment: Your code seems correct, I can't find the error, just try, replace `openerp` with `odoo` and restart a service

Comment: Hi @Anonymousmiliana,I try to change openerp with odoo, but it cant works. May be do you have any solution?

Comment: Same here. Code seems correct, did you check that all dependencies are in the manifest file? hr_payroll module is the one who add hr.payslip so in your project it has to be as dependency.

Comment: Hi @Sorginah, I've added hr_paryoll in manifest file but it cant works till now. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

This error can sometimes happens if the server has not been restarted after the field was added.

Comment: That's more a comment than an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).